# How are DriverManagerDataSource connections created?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have been reading about DriverManagerDataSource in its [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html). And I ran into this sentence:

> **NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not
> actually pool Connections**. It just serves as simple replacement for a
> full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface,
> but creating new Connections on every call.

What is meant by 'on every call'?

For example: I use hibernate and give the EntityManagerFactory a DriverManagerDataSource. Am I to expect that on each and every entity accessing ex. repo.findOne(entity_id), a new connection is created?

What are the differences between connections and hibernate sessions?

When are connections created and when are sessions created?

When do connections get idle or abandoned and what is the affect of being abandoned or idle?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It means that instead of reusing an already established Connection taken from the available connections in the pool it creates every time a new Connection. Here a definition of Connection Pool taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool):

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required.

This means that `DriverManagerDataSource` is not suitable for a production environment because it is very bad performance system, but can be well suited for preliminary tests because it is faster to configure.

Comment: Thank you, can you help with the rest of the questions?